# Android display image in image viewer

Tags: android, image

I'd like to show a png in the built-in image viewer.
Here is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "image/png");
startActivity(intent);
```

It displays a msgbox with a list which contains more than 10 different applications that can display the image.

How to limit the msgbox to two or three applications (the most significant if
possible)?

Answer (score 0):

I belive you cant do that, the point of the Intent is to let the user have to freedom to decide what to use to open it.

Comment: I dont know why you would want to do this, how do you know what apps to leave so the user can choose? What are the most significant to him/her? What happens if you take out of the list the one actually wanted.

Comment: @blindstuff How about a menu "Open with built-in Gallery"? Didn't you even think about that? With such a menu, user knows what will be done if he taps it.